# Create tenant database programatically

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am having a multi-tenancy application developed with Spring boot. In the master table I hold information about the tenant databases. I am trying to create a service, that receives a row from the master table and creates the database for it. Is there a known way to do this in Spring boot? The only information I can find on internet is creating at start up of the application and this is not desired. The master-tenant table is in a master schema and has the following structure:
[image]

The method from the service is as follows:

```
public void createTenant(TenantDTO tenantDTO) {
    tenantepository.save(new Tenant(tenantDTO));
    MasterTenant masterTenant = new MasterTenant();
    masterTenant.setDbName(tenantDTO.getTenantId());
    masterTenant.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    masterTenant.setTenantId(tenantDTO.getTenantId());
    masterTenant.setPassword("password");
    masterTenant.setStatus(EStatus.ACTIVE.name());
    masterTenant.setUserName("root");
    masterTenant.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+tenantDTO.getTenantId());
    DBContextHolder.setCurrentDb(masterTenant.getDbName());
    masterTenantRepository.save(masterTenant);
    multiTenantConnectionProvider.selectDataSource(masterTenant.getTenantId());
    //create schema + create tables from existing entities or run a script of sql
}
```

I would need help figuring out the part with create schema and tables.

Answer (score 0):

One Option that I can think of is having a back-end like Jenkins or AWS Lambda to which you can give the request to create the database in your server pool.

In case of choosing a Jenkins job, you have REST API exposed by Jenkins, which you can make use of to trigger the job. As it is more tied to the dev-ops you can use terraform like script in the jenkins job that accepts the tenant id as a parameter to set that as the database name etc.

Some advantages of using a Jenkins job are

- The job can be long running
- Supports queueing
- Can easily integrate with devops and remove those dependencies with the application
- API based access to trigger a job, view status and logs etc.